# How to call a Python script with dynamic arguments in Google Colab?

Tags: python, dynamic, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to run a python script for batches of data (in Google Colab). I try to save the results dynamically by giving different folder names for each run. For example:

```
counter=counter+1
source='/myfolder/test_' + str(counter)
!python mycode.py --source source
```

It takes the object "source" literally so it wont find something like '/root/source/', but if I try using:

```
!python mycode.py --source '/myfolder/test_' + str(counter)
```

It won't accept the concatenation. Any ideas how to give that argument a dynamic value?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an answer. Basically, it should be put into a variable:

```
source='/myfolder/test_' + str(counter)
run = f'python mycode.py -- source {source}'
!{run}
```